# spresense　FFTアナライザの実装について

Tags: spresense

こちらにあるFFTアナライザを実装したいと考えているのですが上手くいきません。

https://github.com/TE-YoshinoriOota/Spresense_fftanalyzer_sample

Subcore1とMaincoreのコンパイルとSpresense書き込み自体は、error無く出来ているのですが
実装後、ディスプレイへメニューが表示されません。

その前の手順での間違いがあるのかと考えております。

1.DSPコーデックをインストール
Arduino IDE を起動して、メニュー「Example」>「Audio」>「dsp_installer」>「src_installer」にある「src_installer」を開きます。
skecth をコンパイルし、Spresense にフラッシュします。
コンソールを開き、DSP コーデックをインストールする宛先 (SD カード/フラッシュ) を選択します。そして、それをインストールします。
　→こちら、コンソールを開きコーデックインストール先を選択ですが
　ArduinoIDEのシリアルモニタを起動しても選択先が選べず

2. Arduino_Json ライブラリを取得する
   この github でArduino_Jsonをダウンロードします。
   これを Arduino ライブラリ ディレクトリにドロップします。
   　→読んで字のごとく、C:\Users\conso\OneDrive\ドキュメント\Arduino\libraries\ArduinoJson-6.x-spresenseへドロップしましたが、これで合っているのでしょうか？
3. リソース ファイルをストレージにコピーする
   Documents/json内のリソースファイルをSpresense 上の SD カード/Flash のルートにコピーします。
   →AA000.txtなどが入ったフォルダをSDカードルートへコピー

ご教示お願い致します。

下記ディスプレイマイクキットを使用
https://akizukidenshi.com/catalog/g/gM-16589/

Answer (score 1):

ひょっとして動かないのは、3. のリソースファイルのコピーのところではないでしょうか？SDカードのルートにフォルダー「json」をコピーしていませんか？私は、SDカードのルートに AA000.txt などを直接置いていますが、特に問題なく動いています。

Comment: yoshino Taro様

ご指摘の通りフォルダで置いておりました。。。
SDカードのルート直下に「json」内のtxtファイルを置くことで、画面表示が正常に動作しました！
このプログラム自体もYoshino様に以前ご紹介していただいたもので
何から何まで本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score -1):

GitHubのissueチケットを作成して提供者本人に聞いた方が適切な回答がもらえるのでは？

https://github.com/TE-YoshinoriOota/Spresense_fftanalyzer_sample/issues